# is there any inbuilt way of validation,encryption and recovery of password in java

Tags: java, validation, passwords, password-encryption

Instead of comparing a **string**, Is there any inbuilt **class** or **method** in **java** for **validation, encryption** and **recovery** of **password** . Or else is there any usable class library available for such a purposes. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no. It is common to use a [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) to accomplish this, by applying a one way cryptographic hash function to the user's password (e.g. one of SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512 [and there are others]) and a [SALT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to prevent [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) based attacks. All of which can certainly be accomplished with native "inbuilt" Java.